# Can I tint icon in Android shortcut feature?

Tags: android, shortcut

I have an xml like this for Android [shortcut](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) feature:

```
<shortcuts
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="some_id"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/short_label"
        android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/long_label"
        tools:targetApi="n_mr1">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            android:targetPackage="my.package"
            android:targetClass="my.package.MainActivity" />
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>
```

Currently my icon is a vector drawable and it has a white tint.

Can I somehow use a different tint here in the file definition? So something like:

```
<shortcut
    ...
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:iconTint="#0000ff"
    ...>

</shortcut>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There neither is a `android:tint="color"` nor `android:iconTint="color"`.

You could use *Android Studio*'s **Image Asset** to create a shortcut icon (for static shortcuts)

or use dynamic shortcuts and tint them programmatically via `drawable.setTint(tint)`.

Comment: Can you explain how to set the Icon color (for dynamic shortcuts) programmatically?

Comment: Icon icon = Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.your_icon);

Answer (score 2):

Shortcut icons cannot include tints.

[refrence](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts)